# Jquery Send To Phone click link to populate text field in form for keypad

Tags: javascript, jquery, phone-number, keypad

I can't seem to figure this out.

I have a modal keypad that will submit to a php form that will send an EMAIL sms with information regarding the website.

I want people to be able to click on the keypad to insert value's into the text field area. Similar to like using a phone.

My HTML:

```
<script src="http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/phone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Send To Phone -->
<form action="phpmailer.php" method="post" name="theform">

<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="message_success.php">

<div class="send-to-phone-wrapper">
    <div class="send-to-phone">

        <div class="phone-top">

        <input type="text" id="phone" name="10digit" class="phone-enter-number" placeholder="Mobile Number"></div>



        <div class="buttons-wrapper">
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#?stockAlert=1" class="coupon_link"><p>1<br /><span></span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#?stockAlert=2" class="coupon_link"><p>2<br /><span>ABC</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>3<br /><span>DEF</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>4<br /><span>GHI</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>5<br /><span>JKL</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>6<br /><span>MNO</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>7<br /><span>PQR</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>8<br /><span>STU</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>9<br /><span>VXZ</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button-fix"><div class="phone-star"></div></div>
            <div class="phone-button"><a href="#"><p>0<br /><span style="font-size:23px; font-weight:100;">+</span></p></a></div>
            <div class="phone-button-fix"><div class="phone-pound"></div></div>
        </div>

        <div class="choose-carrier-wrapper">

            <div class="choose-carrier">
            <select name="carrier" class="choose-carrier-selections">
                <option value="none" class="choose-styled"></option>
                <option value="att" class="choose-styled">AT&amp;T</option>
                <option value="alltel" class="choose-styled">Alltel</option>
                <option value="cingular" class="choose-styled">Cingular</option>
                <option value="nextel" class="choose-styled">Nextel</option>
                <option value="sprint" class="choose-styled">Sprint</option>
                <option value="suncom" class="choose-styled">SunCom</option>
                <option value="tmobile" class="choose-styled">T-mobile</option>
                <option value="voicestream" class="choose-styled">VoiceStream</option>
                <option value="verizon" class="choose-styled">Verizon</option>
            </select>          
            </div>

               <div class="phone-submit"><input type="submit" value="" name="submit" class="submit-phone"></div>

        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</form>
<!-- End Send To Phone -->
```

My CSS:

```
/* Send To Phone
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.send-to-phone-wrapper {
    width:319px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.send-to-phone {
    width:322px;
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#000;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px #000;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px #000;

}
.phone-top {
}
.buttons-wrapper {
    width:321px;
    height:268px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-right:1px solid #2d3136;
}
.phone-button {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-left:1px solid #2d3136;
    border-right:1px solid #151b22;
    position:relative;    
}
.phone-button-fix {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-left:1px solid #2d3136;
    border-right:1px solid #151b22;
    position:relative;    
    height:66px;
    width:105px;
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/bg-keypad.gif) repeat-x;    
}
.phone-button p {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-top:14px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:23px;
}
.phone-button p span {
    color:#878b90;
    font-size:14px;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 0px #000;
}

.phone-button a:link, .phone-button a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:66px;
    width:105px;
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/bg-keypad.gif) repeat-x;
}
.phone-button a:hover {
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/bg-keypad2.gif) repeat-x;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.phone-button a:active {
    background-image:none;
    background-color:#3559c3;
}
.phone-button a:hover span  {color:#9ac2fa;}
.phone-button a:active p  {text-shadow:0px 0px 5px #000;}

.phone-star {
    height:24px;
    width:25px;
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/phone-star.gif) no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:39px;
}
.phone-pound {
    height:24px;
    width:25px;
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/phone-pound.gif) no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    left:40px;
}
.phone-enter-number {
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:0px 2px 0px #fff;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height:73px;
    width:322px;
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/bg-top.gif) repeat-x;    
}
.choose-carrier-wrapper {
    height:64px;
    position:relative;
    width:322px;
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/bg-choose.gif) repeat-x;    
}
.choose-carrier {
    width:215px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.choose-carrier-selections {
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/phone-carrier.gif) repeat-x;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;    
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:230px;
    height:63px;
    padding-top:42px;
    padding-left:27px;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
     appearance: none;
     font-size:14px;
     font-weight:bold;
     background-color:#000;
     color:#fff;

}
.choose-styled {
}

.submit-phone {
    height:64px;
    width:107px;
    background:url(http://www.busetopizza.com/demo/sendtophone/send.gif) repeat-x;
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    cursor:pointer;    

}
```

I created a jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/muhupower/nkmXe/1/

I have tried many time with random online scripts. I am able to get the value inputting into the form from a link but all the scripts then replace the form with the other value I hit. So if I type 516 my end result is 6.. I need it to continue to populate the form.

Any help?

Comment: Spent a bit trying to figure this out... Would something like this be what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/dhVgU/1/

Comment: Yea, I mean that looks about right.. Is it the correct way to do it? You are not using a HREF but data number... never used that before

Comment: It is certainly one way to do it. The same could in theory be done with `<a>` tags and their `href` attr.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to show a version with `<a>` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/dhVgU/2/

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. I updated my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/muhupower/nkmXe/2/ since you have the nasty skillz.. you know of anyway to automatically make ( ) around the area code then.. and - after the 6th number to make it look like a phone number?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/nkmXe/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to place the numbers inside the input:

```
var i = 0;
        var num = [];
        $(".buttons-wrapper a").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).attr("href") == "clear") {
                num = [];
                $("#phone").val(num);
                i=0;
            }
            else if($(this).attr("href") == "delete") {
                i--;
                var str = $("#phone").val();
                console.log(str);
                if(num.length == 3) {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length-3).substring(1, str.length);
                }
                else if(num.length == 6) {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length-2);
                }
                else {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length-1);
                }
                $("#phone").val(str);
                num.splice(i, 1);
            }
            else {
                if(num.length <= 9) {
                    num[i] = $(this).attr("href");
                    if(num.length == 3) {
                        $("#phone").val("("+$("#phone").val()+num[i]+")-");
                    }
                    else if(num.length == 6) {
                        $("#phone").val($("#phone").val()+num[i]+"-");

                    }
                    else {
                        $("#phone").val($("#phone").val()+num[i]);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });
```

And a fiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/nkmXe/11/

Comment: Anyway to give it a max length of 10 numbers? The form maxlength is not working anymore with the new code... i don't want people to be able to enter more then the right amount of numbers

Comment: @MuhuPower You just have to wrap it in an `if` that allows numbers to be entered as long as the array only has 10 entries. Updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks... U are a wealth of jquery information.. do you get paid to work on here?

Comment: lol, I am still develop this app, and keep running into trouble.. Almost completed. Maybe I can keep you more entertained if you will. check out my new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/muhupower/nkmXe/7/ i want to be able to delete and clear the form.. bc i disabled the keypress and making people use the modal to enter the details.. but if they mess up there is no way for them to fix the number without refreshing the page... any help please?

Comment: @MuhuPower It's because I refined the selector to `button-wrapper a` instead of `buttons-wrapper a`. Fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nkmXe/9/

Comment: The clear is just adding "clear" to the text area, and the "delete" is deleting the hole textarea... that is what clear should do... delete should just backspace one.

Comment: @MuhuPower Took a bit to finally get, but now the delete works properly too.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!, it works great. I am still developing but going to mark this as solved. I still need to do validation, and form sumbmission to text

Comment: @MuhuPower I think those will be two separate issues... Glad it works though!